# Chrome Browser is not opening for running testcases

Tags: php, google-chrome

I have setup of php zendframework , selenium. When running the selenium it is not opening the chrome browser using command:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.LVz3oS/internal --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12953 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.UenPqz
```

if I remove this `--load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.LVz3oS/internal` then only it is allowing to open browser. It is creating an internal extension so how can I remove that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Open Settings and scroll down to privacy
2. uncheck these settings highlighted in image below  in browser setting of chrome

[image]

Comment: i am already using latest chrome browser and latest web driver

Comment: you can not delete extension its the one that drives browser you should

Comment: i changed answer check now